# What to do with white neutral wire?

Tags: wiring

I am installing an electric cooktop that has black and red conductor wires (plus the ground wire). However, the circuit line has black, red and white wires.

Since there isn't a matching white wire in the cooktop can I safely cap the stranded white wire in the circuit line?

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming the US color conventions, that this is wired as 240V, and that the cooktop runs on 240VAC, then yes. Black and red should be the two phases, to provide the 240V service. White would be needed if a circuit required neutral in order to use half of that as a 120V source, but if your cooktop doesn't require that capping it is the right thing to do.

Comment: @keshlam, Sounds like an answer, right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The white wire is simply there in case the device also required 120 volts. as it sounds like the device is straight 240 volts, the white wire is not needed.  Cap it using a twist-on wire connector, or other approved means.